# Python I/O multiprocessing with no Return on function

Tags: python, performance, io, python-multiprocessing

I have a working python script that, in a simplified way, works as follows:

```
open("A", 'r')
open("B", 'r')
open("C", 'w')
for lineA in A:
    part1, part2, part3 = lineA.split(' ')
    for lineB in B:
        if part2 in lineB:
            C.write(lineB)
```

I want to check in file B if a section of the line of file A exists there. If so, write that whole line from file B in a new file C.

The process is somewhat time consuming the way I have designed it (1-I still consider myself a noob with Python, 2-There are at least 4 IF statements running inside the main FOR loop), and now I have started to use input files around 200x larger than previously, so I am getting times of around 5 hours per input file here.

I have tried to use multiprocessing but I can't seem to get it to work.
I tried a simple code inside my main() function initially, without any significant improvement and definitely without using more than one CPU:

```
p = Process(target=multi_thread, args=(arg1,arg2,arg3))
p.start()
p.join()
```

Then I tried the jobs approach:

```
jobs = []
for i in range(4):
    p = Process(target='myfunc')
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

And a pool example I found here in the forums, to which I added a Return statement to my main function:

```
def multiproc(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    (...)
    return lineB   # example of Return statment

def main():
    pool = Pool(4)
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as map_file:
        # chunk the work into batches of 4 lines at a time
        results = pool.map(multi_thread, map_file, 4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The jobs approach actually created the file and then restarted 3 more times the whole process from scratch. This last one gives me the following error:

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

And I also suppose that my Return statement is breaking my loop...
Any suggestions to enable multiprocessing for this piece of code, or also to improve its neatness?

Thanks!

EDIT:
As requested, here is the full messy code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
__author__ = 'daniel'

import os
import re
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
start_time = time.time()

def multi_thread(filePath, datasetFolder, mapFileDataset):
    fout = open('outdude.txt', 'w')
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    cwdgen, sep, id = filePath.rpartition('/')
    dataset = datasetFolder.rsplit("/",1)
    dataset = dataset[1]
    ## Create file
    for i in os.listdir(cwd):
        if ".ped" in i:
            sample_id, sep, rest = i.partition('.ped')
            for i in os.listdir(cwd):
                if sample_id+'.pileupgatk' in i and dataset in i:
                    pileup4map = open(i,'r')
                    snpcounter = sum(1 for _ in pileup4map)-1
                    pileup4map.seek(0)
                    mapout = open(sample_id+'.map', 'w')
                    counter = 1
                    for line in pileup4map:
                        if counter <= snpcounter:
                            mapFileData = open(datasetFolder+'/'+mapFileDataset,'r')
                            line = line.rstrip()
                            chro, coord, refb, rbase, qual = line.split(' ')
                            chrom = chro.strip("chr")
                            counter+=1
                            for ligna in mapFileData:
                                if coord in ligna:
                                    k = re.compile(r'(?=%s )' % coord, re.I)   
                                    lookAhead = k.search(ligna)
                                    k = re.compile(r'(?<= %s)' % coord, re.I)   
                                    lookBehind = k.search(ligna)
                                    if lookAhead and lookBehind != None:
                                        lignaChrom = ligna[:2].rstrip(' ')
                                        if chrom == lignaChrom:
                                            lignaOut = ligna.rstrip()
                                            mapout.write(lignaOut+'\n')
                                            ## For POOL
                                            return lignaOut
                                        else: 
                                            pass
                                    else:
                                        pass
                        else:
                            pass
                    mapout.close()


def main():
    #Multiproc
    # p = Process(target=multi_thread, args=('/home/full_karyo.fa', '/home/haak15', 'dataPP.map'))
    # p.start()
    # p.join()
    # print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    #Jobs
    # jobs = []
    # for i in range(4):
    #     p = Process(target=multi_thread, args=('/home/full_karyo.fa', '/home/haak15', 'dataPP.map'))
    #     jobs.append(p)
    #     p.start()
    #     p.join()

    #Pool
    pool = Pool(4)
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as map_file:
        # chunk the work into batches of 4 lines at a time
        results = pool.map(multi_thread, map_file, 4)
        print(results)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT2:
Following Robert E and TheBigC's advises I re-wrote my code and it is now 13x faster, and not as confusing. I used a dictionary approach that is not as I/O hungry as the previous one, as TheBigC pointed. I am happy enough with the speed so I will leave multiprocessing aside for now. Thanks for the comments!

```
if makemap == True:
    ## Dictionary method - 13X faster
    for i in os.listdir(cwd):
        if ".ped" in i:
            sample_id, sep, rest = i.partition('.ped')
            for i in os.listdir(cwd):
                if sample_id+'.pileupgatk' in i and dataset in i:
                    print("\n\t> Creating MAP file from sample: "+sample_id)
                    pileup4map = open(i,'r')
                    snpcounter = sum(1 for _ in pileup4map)-1
                    pileup4map.seek(0)
                    counter = 1
                    piledic = {}
                    for line in pileup4map:
                        if counter <= snpcounter:
                            line = line.rstrip()
                            #chr21 43805965 G G G
                            chro, coord, refb, rbase, qual = line.split(' ')
                            chrom = chro.strip("chr")
                            piledic[chrom,coord]=int(counter)
                            counter += 1

                    pileup4map.close()
                    mapFileData = open(datasetFolder+'/'+mapFileDataset,'r')
                    mapDic = {}
                    counterM =1
                    for ligna in mapFileData:
                        #22 Affx-19821577     0.737773     50950707 A G
                        chroMap,ident,prob,posMap,bas1,bas2 = ligna.split()
                        mapDic[chroMap,posMap]=int(counterM)
                        counterM +=1

                    listOfmatches = []
                    for item in piledic:
                        if item in mapDic:
                            listOfmatches.append(mapDic[item])
                    listOfmatches.sort()

                    mapWrite = open(sample_id+".map", 'w')
                    mapFileData.seek(0)
                    lineCounter = 1
                    for lignagain in mapFileData:
                        if lineCounter in listOfmatches:
                            mapWrite.write(lignagain)
                        lineCounter +=1
                    mapWrite.close()
                    mapFileData.close()
```

Comment: It would be more useful to people if you posted the actual code, rather than pseudo-code.  From the code you've posted it looks like things would never work beyond parsing the first line in fileA.  As posted, your question is too ambiguous to format an answer without making a ton of assumptions.  Furthermore, the problem you present doesn't really lend itself to multiprocessing/threading at all; which reinforces the belief that it is overly vague.

Comment: Hi TheBigC. I've edited and added the original code. I look at it and it is a big mess, that's why I didn't share initially, but maybe you guys can look at it and understand right away.
And yes, I want to multiprocess this as I have 8 cores available and this task only uses 1, taking 5 hours to complete.

Comment: You're right, it's a big mess. I'd start by splitting at least some of the embedded loops into functions and start testing from the bottom up. And perhaps test the multithreading part separately in a simpler way to understand it without the complexity of your application.

Comment: I agree, it's a mess.  Also, consider that your issue (with speed) might not be CPU related at all, it's possible i/o bound.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the comments. Yeah, I agree it might not be CPU related, but the hard drive load is normal. There must be a way to, for example, divide the file in 4 parts and use one CPU per part/process and at the end join everything. What do you guys think?
Robert, I will try that, thanks.